# Probability of making a fullhouse with a $39$ card deck

Tags: probability, card-games

If i have a stripped deck consisting of only $3$ suits instead of all $4$ suits, what is the probability I am able to make a full house?

I am not sure where to begin but I have the following

$${_{13}C_1}\cdot{_3C_3}\cdot {_{12}C_1}\cdot{_3C_2}=468$$ possible combinations

$$\frac{468}{{_{39}C_5}} = 0.0812\%$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems ok ! What is your doubt ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @trueblueanil - needed some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @Max - Noted for next time